# Using MySQL LIKE or = Operators to Select Encrypted Data

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I've found this [Rijndael 256-bit Encryption (CBC) Class](https://gist.github.com/joshhartman/10342187) for encrypt/decrypt some information in my MySQL Server and it was useful, but how can I select this encrypted data with 'LIKE' or '=' operators?

For example:

```
'SELECT name from tblx WHERE name = "'.$crypt->encrypt('George').'"';
```

or:

```
'SELECT name from tblx WHERE name LIKE "'.$crypt->encrypt('Geo').'%"';
```

Comment: I don't think you can, the hash is completely different when as little as one character changes. Use a like won't work, you can only match with exactly the same string

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading through [this guide to searchable encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql) ([mirror](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-search-on-securely-encrypted-database-fields)). It steps through a lot of insecure solutions to this problem (non-randomized encryption) and eventually builds up to a secure solution.

The secure solution was implemented in an open source library called [**CipherSweet**](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com).